# multiple iframes reloading after lightbox pause button and causing all iframes to only display one video

Tags: jquery, html, css, iframe, html5-video

I made a light box in order to click on an image and display a video.

the problem I was running into was that it wouldn't pause after clicking out of the light box. I found a solution for that by creating a button that when clicked exits the light box and clears out then refreshes the iframe and it works fine.

the problem I am running into though is that I have multiple iframes, and when I click on a different one after clicking the close button, they all refresh to the first iframe and not their own. is there any way around this? thanks.

```
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('.close').click(function(){      
            $('iframe').attr('src', $('iframe').attr('src'));
        });
    });
    </script>

 <div class="vids">
    <!-- First Video-->
    <a href="#img4"  >
        <img src="media/Gratia Promotional Images/ij15.jpg" width="80%">
                  <h3 class="vidDescripts">I have found a very good thing | Isaiah & Julia</h3>
    </a>  
    <a href="#_" class="lightbox" id="img4">
        <div id="videoModal" class="modal hide fade in" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="videoModalLabel" aria-hidden="false" style="display: block; margin-top:10%">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/RVop5Kp67Zw" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="" onpause="true" ></iframe>
            </div>
            <button class="close" onclick="pauseVid()">Click here to close video</button>
          </div>

    <!--Second Video-->
    <a href="#img1">
        <img src="media/Gratia Promotional Images/10.jpg" width="80%">
            <h3 class="vidDescripts">Because you are uniquely you. | Austin & Eliza</h3>
    </a>  
   <a href="#_" class="lightbox" id="img1">
        <div id="videoModal" class="modal hide fade in" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="videoModalLabel" aria-hidden="false" style="display: block;margin-top:10%">
         <div class="modal-body">
             <iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/olJC0yAbaWs" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
            </div>         
                <button class="close" onclick="pauseVid()">Click here to close video</button>
           </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out. I had to make seperate ID's for each iframe and then used `$(#vidID).attr('src', url);` for each video and it worked great!

The final jQuery looks like this:

```
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('.close').click(function(){  
            $('#ijVid').attr('src','https://www.youtube.com/embed/RVop5Kp67Zw');
            $('#aeVid').attr('src','https://www.youtube.com/embed/olJC0yAbaWs');
            $('#scVid').attr('src','https://www.youtube.com/embed/CTxpBGu2wyQ');
            $('#mlVid').attr('src','https://www.youtube.com/embed/QvMIkhlFJ2s');
        });
    });
```